# Was the 'Official Novelisation' of Star Wars: The Force Awakens based purely on the (written) screenplay?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Star Wars: The Force Awakens has received an [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel)) from Alan Dean Foster.

Do we know if this novel was based *solely* on the screenplay or was Foster privy to other restricted sources of information (such as a preview screening of the film or interviews with the screenwriter and Director)?

[image]

Comment: Given how long it takes to write, edit, and publish a novel, I think it would have been impossible for Alan Dean Foster to have viewed the movie.

Comment: @Martha - Hence "*preview* screening"

Comment: Abrams was still editing the movie well into November. I estimate that Foster would've needed to finish writing by July, at the very latest. But I don't actually *know* any details, hence comments, not answer. :)

Comment: @Martha Editing, sure, but that one terminal cancer patient saw it a couple weeks before he was "done," so not being done does not preclude the author from seeing any of it.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - Plus there are "[rushes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dailies)" and "[storyboard animatics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKSlQinKTD8)" he could have seen very far in advance of the film being released.

Comment: Oh look, a downvote. People *hate* self-answered question, despite them being [explicitly encouraged by the site](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Richard - heh. You didn't think it would be THAT easy, did you? </o_ren_ishii>

Comment: @DVK - No, but some haters gotta hate. Apparently having lots of rep means you don't get to self-answer without certain users bad-mouthing you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to this interview with [Yahoo Movies](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/how-to-write-a-top-secret-star-wars-book-force-200727313.html);

### Foster based the novelisation largely on the Kasdan screenplay:

> **What level of security was required for you to access the script? In my imagination, it involves a flash drive that self-destructs after
>   two hours.**
>
> *They didn’t say that, but then, that would be part of the secrecy! [Laughs] No, there are a couple of systems that studios use now to
>   send stuff like that. It probably makes the encryption at the NSA look
>   amateurish. It was sent in pieces to me via email, and it was very,
>   very secure. I used the same system when I did the novelizations of
>   J.J.’s two Star Trek movies, so it was quite easy.*

### He didn't get to see the film in advance but he was shown some of the props, concept art and set photos

> **Were you at least shown the film in advance?**
>
> *No, I just saw it on Saturday morning, the day after it opened. Unlike the two Star Trek films, I didn’t get to see the film while I
>   was writing, which was a shame — it would have made the novelization
>   even better. It always does! I did get to see a fair number of still
>   photos of the settings and the characters in costume. I really made a
>   case for that. I told the studio, “The screenplay describes Rey’s
>   scavenger outfit as being a certain way, but it would be useful if I
>   could see the thing instead of having to invent it — pun not intended
>   — out of whole cloth.” They relented, so I got to see pictures of
>   devices and sets. For example, the descriptions of Maz Kanata’s
>   cantina in the book reflects the images I saw, some of which were
>   completed and some that weren’t.*

### He didn't speak to Jar Jar Abrams during the writing of the book, not even once.

> **Did you have any direct contact with J.J. Abrams during the process?**
>
> *No, I’ve never met J.J. and vice versa. Doing a small film is a 24/7 project, and a film like this more like a 25/7 job. I’ve been on sets
>   with directors making nine figure-plus films and you’re lucky if you
>   can get a midnight meeting with them while they’re eating dinner…. I’m
>   sure we’ll bump into each other one of these days, and talk about
>   anything other than Star Trek and Star Wars.*

Comment: For the record, until I researched this I had no idea Yahoo movies still existed, let alone produces *original content* like interviews...

Comment: Damn. This doesn't address the only thing I actually can't confirm - the oft-guessed idea that he used EARLIER script version. I could not find official confirmation on that, other than the date of the interview I used in my answer

Comment: @DVK - The novel seems pretty true to the WGA leaked script. I guess when/if we get hold of other versions of the script, it should be pretty straightforward to work out which version is the closest.

Comment: if I had a week more of vacation, my main issue would be digging into the whole bloody "Starkiller eats the sun" crap. Unfortunately, Real Life takes precedence

Answer (score 6):

From http://makingstarwars.net/2015/06/alan-dean-foster-on-what-materials-he-used-to-write-star-wars-the-force-awakens-novel/

> Have you seen any of the movie, or did you work from the screenplay alone in writing the novelisation?
>
> ALAN DEAN FOSTER: Just the screenplay, plus some concept art and production visuals.  I really wanted to have access to the latter so that if I describe something, or someone, in the book, it matches what actually appears on the screen.  You know how fans are.  If I give someone sideburns and in the film that character appears without them, it will give rise to 468 blog entries.

Comment: Ironic, since the discrepancies plot wise were far far bigger than the frigging sideburns

Comment: Having not read the book, what were some of the major discrepancies, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Doc - please see my comment under Richard's answer. The stupid "did the Starkiller eat its own sun" was IMHO the biggest one.